# would you like to/ care to

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Let's say I'm going to a Chinese restaurant and I want to invite my friend/colleague. Which is the most appropriate form? What are the differences?

Examples:

> I'm going to get some Chinese food.
>   Care to join? / Would you like to join? / Do you want to join?

Which is the most common form for native speakers?

Comment: "Would you care to..." is a little old-fashioned (in BrE) although it is still understood. "Would you like to..." is probably best, and "do you want to..." is acceptable.

Comment: @Mick And how about simply "Care to join?" in comparison with the rest?

Comment: "Care to join us?" is colloquial. No problem.

Comment: You asked 3 questions, not one. (And questions about what is *the most appropriate* are usually primarily opinion-based, so off-topic.)

Answer (score 2):

"Care to" is more graceful.  It might be a little old-fashioned but it sounds great to my ear.  Your "join" doesn't match in tone very well, though.  The following would sound pleasing:

> Care to come along?

Or

> Would you care to come along?

If you ever have trouble with people understanding your spoken English, then go with the latter ("Would you etc.").

Comment: With the full "would you", "care" sounds very old fashioned, and I'd always use "like". But if I omit the "would you", I would use "care". So "Would you like to join us?", but "Care to join us?".

Comment: @ColinFine - To me "Would you care to" sounds polite and solicitous.  If I were invited with this phrasing, I would be likely to accept, or at least be pleased by the invitation.  What I like about this invitation is that there is no pressure, but the inviter sounds interested in having the other person's company.